# Enable content script in chrome extension programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension and it is working absolutely fine.

Part of the `manifest.json` looks like this:

```
"content_scripts":[
        {
            "js":["js/script.js"],
            "css": ["css/style.css"],
            "matches": ["http://localhost/*", "https://localhost/*"]
        }
    ],
```

so the extension injects the content script only when the domain is `localhost`, which is also working fine. Now I want a way by which the extension popup can have a **`enable extension on this domain`** or **`disable extension on this domain`** in the so the user can **enable/disable the extension according to needs**.

I have seen that in multiple ad-blocker plugins, so I guess it should be possible.

Comment: Either switch to declarativeContent API with RequestContentScript or simply store the state in chrome.storage and read it in the content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm when you are saying store the state in chrome.storage then which state are you referring to? And how exactly will that enable content script on a certain domain?

Comment: With the state approach, the content script runs on all sites.

Comment: I'd try declarativeContent or manual programmatic injection via tabs.executeScript.

Comment: I highly suggest **not** using `declarativeContent.RequestContentScript`: it's broken and unsupported. CSS isn't injected and JS can be injected multiple times on the same page.

Answer (score 3):

This needs two parts:

## Programmatic script injection

Now there's the [`chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/scripting/registerContentScript), which lets you programmatically register content scripts.

```js
chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts([{
    id: "a-script",
    matches: ['https://your-dynamic-domain.example.com/*'],
    js: ['content.js']
}]);
```

## Acquiring new permissions

By using `chrome.permissions.request` you can add new domains on which you can inject content scripts. An example would be:

```js
// In a content script, options page or popup
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.permissions.request({
        origins: ['https://your-dynamic-domain.example.com/*']
    }, granted => {
        if (granted) {
            /* Use contentScripts.register */
        }
    });
});
```

For this to work, you'll have to allow new origins to be added on demand by adding this in your `manifest.json`

```json
{
    "optional_permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

---

There are also tools to further simplify this for you and for the end user, such as
[`webext-domain-permission-toggle` and `webext-dynamic-content-scripts`](https://github.com/fregante/webext-dynamic-content-scripts/blob/master/how-to-add-github-enterprise-support-to-web-extensions.md), which are used by many GitHub-related extensions to add support for self-hosted GitHub installations.

They will also register your scripts in the next browser launches and allow the user the remove the new permissions and scripts as well.

Answer (score 2):

Google is working on programmatic script registration for extension manifest v3. The new API will be called [chrome.scripting.registerContentScript](https://www.extension.ninja/blog/post/chrome-scripting-registerContentScript-is-not-working) and pretty much matches what Firefox already has, minus the intuitive naming of the API. You can follow the implementation status in this [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1054624).